# How do I stop Skype from automatically logging in?

Tags: skype

I log out of the app and it's fine for a while. But it seems to be logging in without me manually doing it, and it's really annoying. And I'm not even logged in on my Laptop!

Comment: Did you log out from the app completely or just close it? If you did and it's still happening, try clearing the cache or the data of the Skype app in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Press the menu button, go to settings, in the privacy section uncheck "Save my password", then sign out.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: Settings screen]